# align the div in same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make the company logo div adjacebt to the name, address, email and iphone container...
i tried giving display inline and float right but its not moving up...
providing my code below....

http://jsfiddle.net/CfzSF/embedded/result/

```
<div style="width: 464px;">

    <div class="page-title">Company Name</div>
    <div style="font-size: 12px; color: #222;">Name:</div>
    <div style="font-size: 12px; color: #222;">Address:</div>
    <div style="font-size: 12px; color: #222;">Email:</div>
    <div style="font-size: 12px; color: #222;">Phone:</div>


</div>


<div style="border: 1px solid #1a4567; width: 100px; float: right;">
    <div>Company</div>
    <div>Logo</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `display: inline-block` - to align elements horizontally

Also, you have the option of using `float` - it will have the same effect.

**EDIT:**

You should also add a `float: left` to the container holding the `name, address, email, and phone` fields. By giving the container holding these elements a `float`, the container will not take up the entire width of the screen, rather, the width of the widest element.

**Working Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ee6GW/4/

Answer (score 0):

Put the float right before the non-floated item.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #1a4567; width: 100px; float: right;">
    <div>Company</div>
    <div>Logo</div>
</div>
<div style="width: 464px;">
    <div class="page-title">Company Name</div>
    <div style="font-size: 12px; color: #222;">Name:</div>
    <div style="font-size: 12px; color: #222;">Address:</div>
    <div style="font-size: 12px; color: #222;">Email:</div>
    <div style="font-size: 12px; color: #222;">Phone:</div>
</div>
```